# JSOUP - Extract Data Web dinamis

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I tried to extract the price. Can anyone please help me? There is no output for the price and its weight ,, I've tried several ways but not out the results

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.jakmall.com/tokocamzone/mi-travel-charger-20a-output-fast-charging#9730928979371").get();

        Elements rows = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "div[dp__price dp__price--2 format__money]");
        System.out.println("rows.size() = " + rows.size());
        String index = "";
        for (Element span : rows) {
            index = span.text();
        }
        System.out.println("index = " + index);
```

I've tried another way but I did not get the result. I was very curious but did not find it the right way

Comment: What is the output of rows.size() ?

Comment: the output is the number of elements derived from "class", "div [dp__price dp__price - 2 format__money]" ,, it is only for trace number of elements obtained, only here I am looking for product price

Comment: I inspect the web site which you send request the site is loading price html element with javascript. So "rows.size()" output is 0. You can't obtain the data rendered via javascript with jsoup. You should use web api (if exists) or something like selenium.

You can test it with searching field in the body with : Files.write(Paths.get("test.txt"),doc.body().text().getBytes());

Comment: but when I search for a name with `Elements rows = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue ("class", "dp__name");`,, I get the name, is there a solution to get the price of the web?

Comment: Because it is getting this <div class="dp__name">
        Mi Travel Charger 2.0A Output Fast Charging
       </div> and this 
         <h1 class="dp__name">Mi Travel Charger 2.0A Output Fast Charging</h1> . It is in the downloaded body with jsoup, price is not.

Comment: is there a solution for me to get the price? because I really need it

Comment: Like I said "You should use web api (if exists) or something like selenium. " You can use selenium with java using chrome/firefox or phantomjs (ghost driver). Take a look : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/selenium/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: that's my problem because it's not given API. okay i'll try to find a way to scrape the web using selenium. thank you for your answer

Comment: why even though I use the link https://www.jakmall.com/search?q=2375618632525, the price does not use javascript but can not be obtained

Comment: Why dont you just try to download html save as string and look inside it.
I shared the code for it. Look at the source code of html it has data : <script type="text/javascript">
        var result = {"products":[{"name":"ASUS X540NA-GO001T Intel N3350 4GB 500GB 15.6 Inch Windows .............. 10""sku":"ASNB53BK","price":4974000,"final_price":3826200.........

Comment: So the result of web page is rendered with javascript.

Comment: hmmmm is there any way to i take the `var result` from the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

if you run this line of code above you will discover thtat there is no price or`div[dp__price dp__price--2 format__money]` DOM. There is only Javascript.

```
String d = doc.getElementsByClass("dp__header__info").outherHtml();
System.out.println(d);
```

Jsoup is not able to fetch the price  because content is loaded dynamically after page loading. Consider using Selenium which more powerfull and supports JavaScript  websites,

Comment: I have successfully used selenium to extract javascript. how to take **Stok Tinggal 4** on `<span class="dp__stock dp__stock--limited"><i class="mi mi-12 marr--sm">info</i>Stok Tinggal 4</span>` without `<i class="mi mi-12 marr--sm">info</i>`, please help me

Comment: do you combine Jsoup with Selenium?

Comment: you can use `replace("info","")` if **info** appears in each element once you have fetch your text under **dp__stock dp__stock--limited**